# How to specify cursor move order?

Tags: vba

I have a userform with several frames and many text boxes.

I want to fill the information from top to bottom, but the cursor moves randomly (vertical and horizontal) between the text boxes.

How can I enter data vertically from top to bottom and at end go to next column?

Comment: `View` >>  `Tab Order` (in the VBA editor) - then click up/down.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the TabIndex property of each one of the controls, so that at each enter stroke or tab stroke the next control is the one that has the next TabIndex value.

Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/forms/set-the-tab-order-using-the-tabindex-property you can find more on this.

Comment: When i edit tab index and moving to another frame the box i edited before will be change automaticly  + there is alot of boxes its hard to change them 1by1

Comment: When you edit a TabIndex it may happen that others TabIndex change  since you might be using an Index that was in use by other control, and so the other control get another Index. There are no repeated Index inside same control.

Comment: There is also some hierarchy in TabIndex. You will have Frame1-> TabIndex 0, Frame2 -> TabIndex1. Inside each frame the Index restarts. So will have the same TabIndex value to TextBox that are contained in different frames. Inside each frame you will controls with TabIndex 0,TabIndex 1,...

Comment: Yap, its hard to change them 1by1. And i don't know if you have any criteria on creating and naming them... It helps. I guess you can define the TabIndex by code, on the initiate event of the form. Example for a frame with two frames and four textbox:  `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Frame 1
Frame1.TabIndex = 0

TextBox1.TabIndex = 0

TextBox3.TabIndex = 1

'Frame2
Frame2.TabIndex = 1

TextBox2.TabIndex = 0

TextBox4.TabIndex = 1

End Sub`